# Show available choice MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a PHP and MySQL beginner. I am currently doing a top up system that include package service. A customer can purchase available packages which define by admin, table are separate into three: customer, package, customer_package. Customer can slowly spend the package money too so amount are turn into record:

```
CUSTOMER(ID ......)
PACKAGE(ID , OFFER_RATE , PRICE )
CUSTOMER_PACKAGE( ID, AMOUNT , CUSTOMER_ID, PACKAGE_ID )
```

I have no problem displaying all choices to the customer, but my problem is if a customer already purchased one of them, how do I only show the rest of the available choices to customer?

My overall idea about the query

```
SELECT * FROM PACKAGE WHERE ID <>(already in customer_package)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM package 
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT package_id 
    FROM customer_package 
    WHERE customer_id = 55
);
```

Or a JOIN

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM package p 
LEFT JOIN customer_package cp ON cp.package_id = p.id AND cp.customer_id = 55 
WHERE cp.id IS NULL
```

Replace 55 with the proper customer id (variable).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the customer's PACKAGE ID up front, your SQL statement will work just fine.

```
SELECT * FROM PACKAGE WHERE ID <>[CUSTOMERS PACKAGE ID]
```

If you don't, you can leverage a subquery..

```
 SELECT * FROM PACKAGE WHERE ID <> (
    SELECT PACKAGE_ID FROM CUSTOMER_PACKAGE WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=[THE CUSTOMER ID]
)
```

if there are more than one records returned in the subquery, you will get an error, in which case, you'll want to use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM PACKAGE WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT PACKAGE_ID FROM CUSTOMER_PACKAGE WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=[THE CUSTOMER ID]
)
```

Comment: Hi mr dutch , thanks for your quick solution , I guess the second 1 is the right query for my situation , just want to confirm some case , because the subquery might return more than one row , erm... i just wondering that will it cause any error?

Comment: See my update. Just curious, *should* there be more than one record for each customer? I would go away from the JOIN method because that requires you pull every relevant record and then use a `WHERE` to filter them out, whereas the subquery is more concise and arguably more efficient.